# React-Native-Styled-Components: Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, styled-components

I am using react-native-Typescript for my app. My styled-components version is    `"styled-components": "^5.3.0"`. I have create custom `ThemeProvider` and wrap to my root app. I have have toggle dark theme for my app. My `ThemeProvider` works fine. I can able to make `DarkTheme` and `LightTheme`. But when I am testing my apps Typescript by using this command `yarn tsc`. I am getting typescript error: `error TS2339: Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'.`. In styled-components it says [Create a declarations file](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#create-a-declarations-file), but it was for version:  `v4.1.4`. And I am using "^5.3.0"`. I really don't how to silent this Typescript Error.

**This is my Theme Colors and it's types**

```
export interface Theme {
  backgroundColor: string;
  primary: string;
  text: string;
  error: string;
}

export const lightTheme: Theme = {
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  primary: '#512DA8',
  text: '#121212',
  error: '#D32F2F',
};

export const darkTheme: Theme = {
  backgroundColor: '#121212',
  primary: '#B39DDB',
  text: '#FFFFFF',
  error: '#EF9A9A',
};

export type TTheme = typeof lightTheme;
```

**This is my Theme Provider**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback, createContext} from 'react';
import {ThemeProvider as SCProvider} from 'styled-components/native';

import {lightTheme, darkTheme} from 'local/theme'; // I am imported the theme


interface ThemeContext {
  theme: string;
  toggleTheme: (value: string) => void;
}

interface ThemeProviderProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContext>({} as ThemeContext);

const ThemeProvider = ({children}: ThemeProviderProps) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const toggleTheme = (value: string) => {
    if (value) {
      setTheme(value);

    }
  };

  const checkForLocalThemeSetting = useCallback(async () => {
    if (localTheme && localTheme !== theme) {
      setTheme(localTheme);
    }
  }, [theme]);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkForLocalThemeSetting();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, toggleTheme}}>
      <SCProvider theme={theme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
        {children}
      </SCProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeProvider;
```

**This is warp my Theme Provider to my root project**

```
  <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <LocalizationProvider>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <Tab.Navigator>
              <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

**In this component I am testing my light and dark**

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, Switch} from 'react-native';

import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import {ThemeContext} from 'local/providers/ThemeProvider';


const Home = () => {

  const {theme, toggleTheme} = useContext(ThemeContext);


  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Wrapper
        style={{}>
        <Text >Hello world</Text>
      </Wrapper>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff'}}
        thumbColor={theme === 'dark' ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={i => {
          if (i) {
            toggleTheme('dark');
          } else {
            toggleTheme('light');
          }
        }}
        value={theme === 'dark'}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const Wrapper = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.backgroundColor}; // Typescript error: error TS2339: Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'.
`;


export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create *declarations file* for initialisation you *DefaultTheme* types as in the documentation. Right now you have a type `interface Theme`  but *styled-component* doesn't know about it. In that case must declare type in the *styled-component*. Try add this the snippet in your *Theme colors types*. [react.js example](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-matan-4j524?file=/src/theme.ts:0-478)

```
import {DefaultTheme} from 'styled-components/native';

declare module "styled-components" {
  export interface Theme {
    backgroundColor: string;
    primary: string;
    text: string;
    error: string;
  }
}

export const lightTheme: DefaultTheme = {
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  primary: "#512DA8",
  text: "#121212",
  error: "#D32F2F"
};

export const darkTheme: DefaultTheme = {
  backgroundColor: "#121212",
  primary: "#B39DDB",
  text: "#FFFFFF",
  error: "#EF9A9A"
};
```

Comment: instead of this `import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";` I did this `import {DefaultTheme} from 'styled-components/native';`