# How to setup styled-components' "css prop" in a React Native + Typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to setup my Expo project so that Styled Components' "css prop" correctly works with TypeScript.

So far I:

- Installed `@types/styled-components`, `styled-components`, and `babel-plugin-styled-components`;
- Enabled the Babel plugin;
- Created a `types/styled.d.ts` file where I defined my own theme as explained by the styled-components documentation;
- Added a `ThemeProvider` wrapper around my App component and assigned it my theme;
- Added `/// <reference types="styled-components/cssprop" />` to the top of my `App.tsx`

  - I also tried with `import type {} from 'styled-components/cssprop';`
  - I tried also `import {} from 'styled-components/cssprop';` but it generated an error: `styled-components/cssprop could not be found within the project.`

This got me in a good place where I can use the `css` property on any React component and it gets properly applied as style.

The last remaining problem I'm having is that when I try to use my theme, as follows, I get a `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)` error:

```
<View
  css={`
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing.small}px;
  `}
>
  <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, I would expect the `props` argument to be populated with my Styled Components' theme.

For completeness, this is my `types/styled.d.ts`:

```
// import original module declarations
import 'styled-components';

// and extend them!
declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    spacing: {
      small: 8;
      medium: 16;
      large: 24;
    };
  }
}
```

My project is just the default expo-cli typescript template.

Comment: Can this answer be helpful? [React-Native-Styled-Components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68921165/15545116)

Comment: @ЖнецЪ I already done that (point 3 of my list)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following on your `types/styled.d.ts`

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface Attributes {
    css?: Interpolation<ThemeType>;
  }
}
```

Full file:

```
import type {Interpolation} from 'styled-components';
import theme from './theme';

type ThemeType = typeof theme;

// Types for styled.COMPONENT
declare module 'styled-components/native' {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeType {}
}

// Types for Css prop
declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeType {}
}

declare module 'react' {
  interface Attributes {
    css?: Interpolation<ThemeType>;
  }
}
```

In short, `CSSProp` is `export type CSSProp = Interpolation<any>;`
but for some reason it is not getting the `DefaultTheme` you defined above.

BTW, you can do this, instead of writing your theme types.

```
type ThemeType = typeof theme; // theme is your object

declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeType {}
}
```

Theme file:

```
const baseTheme = {
  radix: {
    small: '4px',
    medium: '8px',
    large: '16px',
  },

  paddings: {
    4: 4,
    8: 8,
    12: 12,
    16: 16,
    20: 20,
    24: 24,
    28: 28,
    32: 32,
  },

  fontSizes: {
    extraSmall: 4,
    small: 8,
    body: 14,
    h5: 16,
    h4: 18,
    h3: 20,
    h2: 22,
    h1: 24,
  },

  fontWeight: {
    300: 300,
    400: 400,
    500: 500,
  },
};

export const light = {
  ...baseTheme,

  colors: {
    white: '#fff',
  },
};

export const dark = {
  ...baseTheme,

  colors: {
    white: '#fff',
  },
};

const theme = light;

export default theme;
```

I hope this help.
Best of luck